# Remove white space between some fields but not others

Tags: perl

I'm getting really frustrated by this and would be very grateful if anyone could help. Id like to change this so that the last 3 fields are printed together and not separated by a space, but keep the space after the first. Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %throne = ('Ala' => 'A',
              'Cys' => 'C',
              'Asp' => 'D',
          'Pro' => 'P',
          'Val' => 'V',
          'Leu' => 'L',
          'Ile' => 'I',
          'Met' => 'M',
          'Phe' => 'F',
          'Tyr' => 'Y',
          'Trp' => 'W',
          'His' => 'H',
          'Lys' => 'K',
          'Arg' => 'R',
          'Gln' => 'Q',
          'Asn' => 'N',
          'Glu' => 'E',
          'Ser' => 'S',
          'Thr' => 'T',
          'Gly' => 'G');


while(<>)
{
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    print $fields[0] . " " . $throne{$fields[1]} . " " . $fields[2] . " " . $throne{$fields[3]} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the space in the `. " " .` part?

Comment: Show your input and desired output.

Comment: Input is: 
P45381 ARG 168 CYS PD
Desired output:
P45381 R168C

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
print $fields[0] . " " . $throne{$fields[1]} . $fields[2] . $throne{$fields[3]} . "\n";
```

Comment: I'd tried that but then I lose the two hashed fields, so it just prints fields 0 and 2...